# Loop through columns applying function between select columns

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = "T2", Height = 1.2, 
              Number_2 = 1, node_age_2 = 0, 
              Number_3 = 1, node_age_3 = 1, 
              Number_4 = 1, node_age_4 = 2)
```

I need to loop through this dataframe applying a complex series of functions. I am unsure about looping through each column and how to implement. The steps I envision are:

1. Start at the lowest value column `Number_2:node_age_2`
2. Apply function `Answer_2 = Number_2 + node_age_2`
3. Apply function `Answer_3 = Number_3 + node_age_3`
4. `if (Answer_3 < Answer_2){Answer_3} ELSE {Answer_2}`
5. Continue sequentially the end of the dataframe.

In the end, the final product would look something like:

```
id Height Number_2 node_age_2 Answer_2 Number_3 node_age_3 Answer_3 Number_4 node_age_4 Answer_4
1 T2    1.2        1          0        1        1          1        1       1          2        1
```

I've greatly simplified this function. My true dataset is much larger than this (115 sets of variables) and actually has many different columns within each number. I just need to understand this simple example to get started. So the idea is to loop through without calling each name.

Comment: @RyanD Edited accordingly

Comment: @RyanD Yes, I am always comparing to `Answer_2` and only taking a new `Answer` if it is less than the previous `Answer`. So in this example, everything is compared to answer 2, but in practice it is just compared to the previous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reshape your data to "long" format, you can get the sums with a grouping operation

```
library(tidyverse)

Answers <- 
  dat %>% 
    gather(key = 'NumNode', value = 'value', Number_2:node_age_4) %>% 
    group_by(grp = parse_number(NumNode)) %>% 
    do(Answer = with(.data, value[grep('Num', NumNode)] + value[grep('node', NumNode)]))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     grp Answer
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  2.00   1.00
# 2  3.00   2.00
# 3  4.00   3.00
```

Then your `if` logic can be implemented by just `accumulate`ing the `min`

```
answers <- accumulate(Answers$Answer, pmin)
# [1] 1 1 1
```

You can add the results as columns of `dat` with

```
dat[paste0('Answer_', Answers$grp)] <- ifelse(is.list(answers), answers, as.list(answers))
```

Example data having > 1 row

```
dat <- data.frame(id = "T2", Height = 1.2, 
              Number_2 = 1:2, node_age_2 = 0:1, 
              Number_3 = 1:2, node_age_3 = 1:2, 
              Number_4 = 1:2, node_age_4 = 2:3)
```

Output from method above

```
  id Height Number_2 node_age_2 Number_3 node_age_3 Number_4 node_age_4 Answer_2 Answer_3 Answer_4
1 T2    1.2        1          0        1          1        1          2        1        1        1
2 T2    1.2        2          1        2          2        2          3        3        3        3
```